# Incomplete gamma function algorithm

Tags: c++, gamma-function

There is a very concise algorithm for computing lower incomplete gamma function:

https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/asa147/asa147.html

We coded this in C++. There is one thing I don't understand in this algorithm. In one place to compute the following expression:

[image: \frac{\gamma(p,x)}{\Gamma(p)}]

it is substituted by:

[image: x^p e^{-x}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{x^k}{\Gamma(k+p+1)},]

Obviously this is the same, but why it is done like this? Is computing exp of lgamma more efficient than computing tgamma function (both `lgamma` and `tgamma` are available in C++)?

Answer (score 3):

> Does computing exp of lgamma is more efficient than computing tgamma function (both lgamma and tgamma are available in C++)?

computing lgamma is more efficient because it is basically n*log(n) behavior.
So typically you have good approximation id you're trying to compute
lgamma(x)/x function.

also, keep in mind, that `lgamma` is often used because it is part of expression which could be computed while `tgamma`, which is growing as fast as factorial, is not. So it is safe to compute whole expression `f(x)` as exp(log(f(x))), and if f(x) has product of `tgamma`, then log(f(x)) will have to sum/substract `lgamma`.

Good way to avoid overflow, basically

Answer (score 0):

You will find proper implementations of the Gamma for c++ here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_gamma